# AFNetworking 2 with NSURLCache doesn't work on ios8

Tags: caching, ios8, afnetworking-2, nsurlcache

I use `AFNetworking 2` and request date with `SharedInstance().GET` method, but cache doesn't work on iOS 8. It request it again and again, even in offline mode. But It worked perfect on iOS 7. I tested it in simulators and real devices.

Max-age header on my web-server:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=21600
```

Cache setup on application `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
let urlCache = NSURLCache(memoryCapacity: 1024*1024*4, diskCapacity: 1024*1024*5, diskPath: nil);
NSURLCache.setSharedURLCache(urlCache)
```

Also I check reachability and set cacheMode for offline

```
override func dataTaskWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest!, completionHandler: ((NSURLResponse!, AnyObject!, NSError!) -> Void)!) -> NSURLSessionDataTask! { 
    let modifiedRequest : NSMutableURLRequest = request.mutableCopy() as NSMutableURLRequest
    let reachability : AFNetworkReachabilityManager = AFNetworkReachabilityManager.sharedManager()
    if (!reachability.reachable) {
        modifiedRequest.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad
    }
    return super.dataTaskWithRequest(modifiedRequest, completionHandler: completionHandler)
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it iOS 8 bug or something else?

*some update:*

I tried to monitor my cache size:

```
println("disk \(NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().currentDiskUsage) of \(NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().diskCapacity)")
println("memory \(NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().currentMemoryUsage) of \(NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().memoryCapacity)")
```

And cache does't grow on iOS8 after my `sharedInstance().GET` requests. Cache grows only by `setImageWithURLRequest` method of `UIImageView+AFNetworking` class. In iOS7 it works good both ways. I think the issue can be with `NSURLSessionDataTask` requests in iOS 8.

Comment: currentDiskUsage appears to be returning incorrect results (never changing, and much smaller than the actual usage) in my testing. I can see files being stored in fsCachedData (far too many, my cache size is now 300MB and some of my users have complained that their sizes are up to 1GB!).

Comment: Having tested on iOS 7 it seems that currentDiskUsage lags a bit behind reality there - but at least it does change!

Comment: Seems like a bug, you can check [this](http://blog.airsource.co.uk/2014/10/11/nsurlcache-ios8-broken/) series of posts regarding NSURLCache issues on iOS 8